# Get autoincrement id after an insert query performed with a prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, auto-increment

If I execute an insert query with a stored procedure with php and the mysqli`_`* functions, is there a way to retrieve the value of an autoincrement id field?
`mysqli->insert_id` does not seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you can post your table definition. Or double-check that there is an `auto_increment` set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure the last query you preformed was an INSERT?

[`mysqli->insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) seems the proper answer:

> ### Return Values
>
> The value of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field that was updated
> by the previous query. Returns zero if
> there was no previous query on the
> connection or if the query did not
> update an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.

Comment: You are right, I was making a mistake in my code, mysqli->insert_id actually works also with prepared statements. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You could try to make a [query to MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) like so:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Not sure if it works with stored procedures though.

Answer (score 1):

You could add this statement in your stored procedure after the insert:

```
   SET @saved_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Then, execute this query after calling the procedure:

```
   SELECT @saved_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli->insert_id` (where `mysqli` represents your database connection)
must be used directly after the insert. If you run other queries on the same connection
before attempting to read `insert_id` you get 0 returned.